# No 3D after Ubuntu 11.10 updates - T420s Intel Sandy Bridge

Tags: unity, intel

At rebooting my Lenovo ThinkPad T420s after the recent updates coming last Friday (not sure), I got severe graphical problems: could almost not use unity.

I switched from Intel to Nvidia and loaded the restricted driver. Then I saw some more updates coming and applied them.

When I switched back to Intel graphics (integrated), I got only Unity 2D. So no 3D any more on Intel.

Any hints other than waiting for another update that fixes the issues?

Comment: Did you remove the restricted drivers and the `xorg.conf` generated for them?

Comment: Not explicitly, but I tried to clean up with:
$ sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg
$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-video-all
$ sudo reboot
(from hint in http://askubuntu.com/questions/79403/ubuntu-11-10-is-falling-back-to-unity-2d-how-to-get-back-to-unity-3d). It looks like it tries unity 3d at login but backs down to unity 2d.

Answer (score 1):

Probem solved: I had power tuned my ubuntu with the hint in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1872633. But some of the packages installed in that instruction interfered with the kernel or intel driver update, and 3d stopped working. When I removed the PPA-sources and packages in the article above and rebooted, 3d worked again.